# How to get trigger function and function of PostgreSQL with SQL differently?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, function

I want to get the functions and trigger functions separately, with sql from JDBC, not command line.

update:
Sorry, it's not clear enough. I mean, trigger function is also a function. how can I tell a trigger function from normal function with sql?

As far as I know is, trigger function's return type is `trigger`, is it enough to use this to distinguish?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Try to provide some more explanations and maybe an example

Answer (score 8):

To get the function source:

```
select pg_get_functiondef('public.your_trigger_function()'::regprocedure);
```

To get the trigger definition

```
select pg_get_triggerdef(oid)
from pg_trigger
where tgname = 'name_of_your_trigger';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all user-defined functions with the SQL below. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-routines.html) explains `information_schema.routines`:

```sql
SELECT routine_name 
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_type IS DISTINCT FROM 'PROCEDURE'
AND specific_schema != 'pg_catalog'
AND specific_schema != 'information_schema';
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT routine_name 
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE (routine_type != 'PROCEDURE' OR routine_type IS NULL)
AND specific_schema != 'pg_catalog'
AND specific_schema != 'information_schema';
```

And, you can get all user-defined trigger functions with the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT routine_name 
FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE data_type = 'trigger' AND specific_schema != 'pg_catalog';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select tgname, 
       pg_get_triggerdef(oid),
       CASE 
            WHEN split_part(pg_get_triggerdef(oid), 'FUNCTION', 2) IS NOT NULL 
                THEN pg_get_functiondef(split_part(pg_get_triggerdef(oid), 'FUNCTION', 2) ::regprocedure)   
            ELSE pg_get_functiondef(split_part(pg_get_triggerdef(oid), 'PROCEDURE', 2) ::regprocedure)  
       END
from pg_trigger
where tgname = 'test_updated';
```